# why is the output result of sha-256 always 256 bits and the execution time always the same?

Tags: encryption, sha256, bitcoin, computation

Why is it, that no matter the size of the input of the SHA-256 algorithm (in bitcoin mining), it always outputs a result of 256 bits?

furthermore, how come that no matter the size of the input, the computation time is always the same?

Comment: Bitcoin compresses two blocks for each attempt. It doesn't use variable size inputs in the inner mining loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your first question, the answer would be that it is by design - the SHA-256 algorithm is intended to take an arbitrary amount of input data and produce 256 bits of output, whilst also maintaining certain [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Properties) that make for an effective cryptographic hash. Other hash algorithms produce different output sizes (e.g. SHA-1 produces 160 bits of output, SHA-512 produces 512 bits of output, etc.).

Your second question is based on an incorrect assumption - the computation time *is* dependent on the size of the input - it will naturally take longer even just to read say, a 1MB file than it would to read a 1KB file, and since the hash is dependent on every bit of the input, a larger input will take longer to hash than a smaller one.

Comment: In bitcoin, the inputs to the SHA-256 hash are so trivially small that the amount of computation time is also small.

Answer (score 1):

Output size is the same as it (algorithm) was designed this way.

Input size matters - just compute hash of 1GB file and 1KB file and compare - you'll see speed diff.